# Forcing javascript to read latter code

Tags: javascript, tumblr

I'm trying to use this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementById("towerwrapper").style.height=document.documentElement.clientHeight;
</script>
```

To stretch a div to make a dynamically-resizing image for a tumblr theme. Essentially it should create a tower that stretches from the top to the bottom of the page, is centered, and is partially obscured by the posts. The tower itself involves a wrapper and a series of divs formatted like this:

```
#towerwrapper {
   position:absolute;
   width:100%;
   top:0px;
   z-index: -10;
}

#floor6 {
   height:16.6%;
   width:192px;
   background: url("http://imageshack.us/a/img37/7831/i1v.png") repeat-y center bottom;
   margin:0 auto;
}

#floor5 {
   height:16.6%;
   width:256px;
   background: url("http://imageshack.us/a/img594/1337/ug6.png") repeat-y center bottom;
   margin:0 auto;
}

#floor4 {
   height:16.6%;
   width:416px;
   background: url("http://imageshack.us/a/img545/6572/b522.png") repeat-y center bottom;
   margin:0 auto;
}

#floor3 {
   height:16.6%;
   width:448px;
   background: url("http://imageshack.us/a/img16/3695/qrd.png") repeat-y center bottom;
   margin:0 auto;
}

#floor2 {
   height:16.6%;
   width:480px;
   background: url("http://imageshack.us/a/img824/5330/thq.png") repeat-y center bottom;
   margin:0 auto;
}

#floor1 {
   height:16.6%;
   width:543px;
   background: url("http://imageshack.us/a/img51/6671/8g2.png") repeat-y center bottom;
   margin:0 auto;
}
```

They're then inlaid pretty basically:

```
<div id="towerwrapper">
<div id="floor6"><img src="http://imageshack.us/a/img843/4886/eu6.png"></div>
<div id="floor5"><img src="http://imageshack.us/a/img18/3192/cfnp.png"></div>
<div id="floor4"><img src="http://imageshack.us/a/img690/1014/9rph.png"></div>
<div id="floor3"><img src="http://imageshack.us/a/img543/7551/6d.png"></div>
<div id="floor2"><img src="http://imageshack.us/a/img856/5430/7tb.png"></div>
<div id="floor1"><img src="http://imageshack.us/a/img849/1158/jx44.png"></div>
</div>
```

Everything works perfectly up until it's placed into the blog itself. Unfortunately, the line of javascript can't read the full height of the page, since Tumblr automatically adds the javascript used to insert the posts *after* the rest of the theme.

Is there a way to force the script to read the posts? If not, would there be a better way to ensure that the wrapper maintains the full page size?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the javascript is being run at the start of the page.

Try this to run it only after the page is finished loading:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function adjustTower() {
       document.getElementById("towerwrapper").style.height=document.documentElement.clientHeight;
   }
   window.onload = adjustTower;
</script>
```

On the off chance the content is being loaded asynchronously, you may want to try executing the adjustment after a timeout:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       function adjustTower() {
           setTimeout(function () { 
               document.getElementById("towerwrapper").style.height=document.documentElement.clientHeight;
           },500);
       }
       window.onload = adjustTower;
</script>
```

Comment: Neither of these seem to have any effect at all, unfortunately. Not sure why. (And pardon me if I'm making blatant mistakes; I'm mainly knowledgeable in CSS/CSS3 and Javascript is fairly new to me.)